# How to change the color of selected ltem in a ListView which is used a drawer options

Tags: android, listview

I am using a DrawerLayout which contains a Linear layout, inside LinearLayout there is ListView. This LinearLayout is used as a drawer and ListView is used as options inside the Drawer. I have used a method called setItemChecked() which gives a default pink color to the option which is selected in a ListView. i want to remove that default pink color and want to use my own color. Tried so many thing such as selector, setSelected(true), listSelector, Nothing worked out even sometime the background color of the selected option changed, but the default pink color was still there. Please Help!!!
I am unable to post the image but here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
tools:context=".ExpenseActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list_of_drawers"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Version 1.0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_of_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:listSelector="@color/greenBlue"

        />

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I just want to change the color which is provided by setItemChecked() method

```
//ListView's OnClickListener
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        //code when item gets clicked
        view.setSelected(true);
        selectItem(position);
        setActionBarTitle(position);
    }


//SETTING THE LISTENTRIES DATA TO LISTVIEW USING ARRAYADAPTER
    actualList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, listEntries));


//SETTING setOnItemClickListener SO THAT LISTVIEW LISTENS TO OUR CLICKS
    actualList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());


actualList.setItemChecked(currentPosition, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Touch Selectors 
you need to create new xml file in your Drawable folder
with root of Selectors`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryLight" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryLight"android:state_activated="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryLight" android:state_selected="true" />


<item android:drawable="@android:color/background_light" /> 
</selector>`
```

Iam assuming each view is Linear layout
then you need to set background of you ListView's view to your Touch Selector xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector">
```

Answer (score 0):

Define list_activated_background.xml file in drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="yourColorOrDrawable" /> 
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="yourColorOrDrawable" /> 
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="yourColorOrDrawable" /> 
    <item android:drawable="yourDefaultColorOrDrawable" /> 
</selector>
```

In your AppTheme style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_activated_background</item>
</style>
```